# copy values of two column of a table into a column from another table

Tags: sql

I am going to have value of two columns from one table in a column of another table. I do not know correct code. Even for copying one column to another when I use this code, it just shows blank field in destination column.

```
insert into Send_RecCode(Send_RecName)
select (Sender) 
from table1
```

Comment: Edit our question and (1) provide sample data and desired results; (2) tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Probably asking for UPDATE.

Comment: Do you want to insert two columns data into one column of another table ? or two columns from one into two columns to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
INSERT INTO Send_RecCode(Send_RecName)
SELECT CONCAT(Sender, receiver) FROM table1
```

Comment: I make a new query in sql server 2014 and copy your code and execute it but it shows blank on destination column

Comment: Can you please verify the size of destination & source (datatype may be same) column because It's working perfectly in my data and it also handle the NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited as per OP's question**

Try this:

Check Your datatypes are same in two tables, and then try this.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (send_RecName )
SELECT sender + '' + receiver FROM Table1;
```

Try this:
It works perfectly for me

```
 INSERT INTO [Staffs]([FName])
 SELECT [FName]+' '+[LName]   FROM [student]
```

Comment: I have to mention that I have two field names sender and receiver in one table and I want to copying their value in one field of another table named send_RecName

Comment: @Sunash B I make a new query in sql server 2014 and copy your code and execute it but it shows blank on destination column

Comment: @bz.morvarid See the update answer which works perfectly for me.

Comment: @bz.morvarid Check your datatype,i think there might be difference,please go through that.

Answer (score 0):

please try using below code, hope it will work

insert into Send_RecCode(Send_RecName)

select  Sender  from table1